# Windows service downloading the references on installing executable file

Tags: c#, reference, installation, windows-services

I have created a Windows service which communicates with AWS, so that I have added Amazon dlls as references. Now as we know that the problem is without the dlls service will not workout. So I want to download the dlls while installing the executable file into the same directory.

Anybody have solution for this problem?

Comment: If you download one at install time, your installer would need to ensure binary compatibility. Why not just ship them with your assembly?

Comment: Ask your self whats easier, writing code to download and install dlls or just including the dlls in the install program or zip file or what ever you are using

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding the primary output to a setup project. While installing the Windows Setup, it automatically retrieves all the dependent files for the service so as we configured.